# Simple way to pass a LangChain chain variables that are nested in the previous chain's response?

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

I'm building a `SequentialChain` in LangChain. The first chain responds with a dictionary that has some nesting such as:

```py
{
  'a': {
         'c': 'foo',
         'd': 'bar'
         ...
       },
  'b': 'baz'
}
```

I can specify the chain's `output_variables` as `'a'` or `'b'` or both of course. But is there a simple way to give the values for `'c'` and `'d'` here as inputs to the next chain in the sequence without flattening the dict itself?